# Warnings about built-in functions in cross-compiled c

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling

Code:

```
#include <string.h>
//Return copy of str string from index position and len length
char *StrCpy2(char *str, unsigned short index, unsigned char len)
{
    char *text;
    text = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    if (text == NULL) return text;
    strncpy(text, str + index, len);
    text[len] = '\0';
    return text;
}
```

Console output respecting this file and lines:

```
Compiling file: String.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffast-math -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wextra -std=gnu99 -g -ggdb3 -fverbose-asm -Wa,-ahlms=out/String.lst  -DSTM32F40_41xxx  -DUSE_STM324x7I_EVAL  -MD -MP -MF out/String.d -I.  -IBACnet/inc  -IBACnet/inc/objects  -Iinc  -Ilib/drivers/inc  -Ilib/eval  -IUI/inc  -IuIP/inc String.c -o out/String.o
String.c: In function 'StrCpy2':
String.c:39:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strncpy' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  strncpy(text, str + index, len);
  ^
String.c:39:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strncpy'
String.c:39:2: note: include '<string.h>' or provide a declaration of 'strncpy'
```

I feel lost because something went wrong during porting from stm32f1 to stm32f4, and codesourcery toolchain to bleeding-edge-toolchain [(this one)](http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/articles/35-arm/87-bleeding-edge-toolchain-o-co-chodzi). As you can see I already include . Maybe some #defines are not correct? Maybe some paths in eclipse or system are wrong?

Comment: Sound as if `strncpy` is not defined in `string.h` in the other toolchain. You can check this easily by inspecting the `string.h` file.

Comment: Find all files named `"string.h"` under your IDE's path (typically in a folder named `"include"`). Search for `strncpy` within each and every one of these files. Sounds like the one that you include in your stm32f1 project declares this function, but the one that you include in your stm32f4 project does not. Finally, in your stm32f4 project settings, change your `include` path to be the same as the one in your stm32f1 project settings.

Comment: Are you sure there is a declaration of `strncpy` in `string.h`? It _should be_ there, but maybe you're using some outdated toolchain or something. Anyway, you can write this function yourself, it's not so hard to do it.

Comment: Anyway using `strncpy` is a bad idea because you may end up with a string without NUL terminator. [Read this](https://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/).

Comment: @MichaelWalz: `text[len] = '\0'` in OP's code takes care of that.

Comment: strcpy declaration is in place. Eclipse do not gray it out because of defines. string.h file is in `c:\Tools\ARM\bet\arm-none-eabi\include\ `path, and i have this path along with `c:\Tools\ARM\bet\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\5.3.1\include\ ` and `c:\Tools\ARM\bet\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\5.3.1\include-fixed\ `in eclipse project settings, `Preprocessor Include Paths Macros etc.`
strncpy declaration:
`char  *_EXFUN(strncpy,(char *__restrict, const char *__restrict, size_t));`
I have forgotten to inform - I have same problem with almost every build-in function in project, just chosen this as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain, that you have a file named `String.h` in your project. Because you compile that on Windows, which is not smart enough to notice a difference between your `String.h` and toolchain's `string.h`, the line `#include <string.h>` actually includes your `String.h`, where you most likely don't have that declaration.

If you'd compile that on Linux, it would most likely work, because the case of file names matters there. For Windows you have no other solution than to name your file (especially the header) differently. Personally I'd propose to have a single global function per module (header + source) and then you can name the module after the function. So in above case you'd have `StrCpy2.h` and `StrCpy2.c`.